# counting number of particular elements in a object JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

If you have an object such as this:

```
var obj = {
exampleOne : 0,
exampleTwo : 1,
exampleThree : 0,
}
```

How would you be able to count the number of 0's inside the object without using a loop?

Comment: n=Object.values(obj).filter(function(el) {
return el==0;
}).length;

Comment: `var count = Object.keys(obj).reduce((acc, key) => acc + (obj[key] === 0? 1: 0), 0);`